# What does extra parameter mean in this for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have come across a for-loop that is unusual to me. What does `method` mean in this for-loop?

`for method, config in self.myList.items():`

Comment: It seems `self.myList.items()` is returning a `tuple` or `list` with 2 entries (e.g. `(entry1, entry2)`). In the example case `method` would be `entry1`, `config` would be `entry2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`items()` is a method used on python `dictionaries` to return an `iterable` holding `tuples` for each of the dictionary's `keys` and their corresponding `value`.

In Python you can unpack `lists` and `tuples` into variables using the method you've shown.

e.g.:

```
item1, item2 = [1,2]
# now we have item1 = 1, item2 = 2
```

Therefore, assuming `self.myList` is a `dict`, `method` and `config` would relate to the `key` and `value` in each `tuple` for that iteration respectively.

If `self.myList` is not a `dict`, I would assume it either inherits from `dict` or it's `items()` method is similar (you would know better).

Answer (score 4):

It's unpacking a tuple returned from the `items()` call into the `method` and `config` variables.